# Multiprocessing in Python: web scraping doesn't speed up

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I would like to use the multiprocessing module to speed up web scraping. 
My goal is to extract a part of HTML in a page and save it in a parent variable.
Finally, write that variable into a file.

But the problem I have is that it takes around 1 second to process a page.

My code works, but it does not do what I want:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # This is a thread-based Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def parseWeb(url):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    h2_tag = soup.find('h2', class_='midashigo')
    return h2_tag

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = 'links.txt' # each link is on a separate line.
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() * 2)
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        results = pool.map(parseWeb, f)
    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as w:
        w.write(str(results))
```

How can it be modified to give it the full power of multiprocessing? Thank you.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is this on windows or linux?

Comment: @Leon this is on windows. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that your threaded process is big enough to get any boost from multi-threading. Python multi-threading is most effective with largish `payloads` which do a fair amount of either I/O or external C/C++ library calls (i.e. where the GIL is released). You might find better results with a multi-processing solution.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 You're right. I have nearly 420,000 pages to process. I write the code based on the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373167/multithreading-in-python-beautifulsoup-scraping-doesnt-speed-up-at-all   But it doesn't speed up. Taking up 1 second to process 1 page while there are 420,000 pages, the speed is crucial.

Comment: @DanEng, you could try doing more than one file in a thread - so that you get some I/O - but I doubt that will solve the problem. It maybe that you need a different solution.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373167/multithreading-in-python-beautifulsoup-scraping-doesnt-speed-up-at-all?rq=1

Comment: @ikaros45 Thanks. I have read it. And I'm still trying to imitate that idea to make my project work. Thank you.

Comment: @DanEng - They key here is to find what is being consumed in your thread - is it I/O bound, or CPU bound - if it is I/O bound then multi-threading or multi-processing may not help (as the speed will depend on your network or disk speeds). If it is CPU bound then you need to ensure that as much of your CPU is spent not on python tasks. Is Beautiful Soup a C library or python ?

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 While running the code, my CPU usage is being used 2-3% on average, and the network usage is about 2%. I haven't figured out the problem yet.

Comment: How long do you think it should take?

Comment: @Leon I expect that it should finish running in 24 hours. But thank you for your answer. It is clear!

Answer (score 7):

This process should be I/O bound, meaning your bottle neck should be how much you can pull down the connection before parsing, but in practice it may turn out to be CPU or memory bound.

The first thing you need to realize is that multithreading/processing is not going to speed up individual page parsing times. So if one page takes one second and you have 420000 pages it will take 420000 seconds. If you up the number of thread to the amount of cores your PC has times two and you pc has 4 cores, then you are going to have 8 threads running 1 second each per page. You still end up with 420000 / 8 seconds which is 875 minutes (in practice this will not be entirely true), which is 14.5 hours worth of processing....

For the time spans to be manageable you will need about 400 threads, which will bring processing time down to a theoretical 17 odd minutes.

With so many threads running and pages being parsed memory is going to become a problem as well.

I slapped together this little app to test some times

```
from time import sleep

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def f(x):
    sleep(1)
    x = int(x)
    return x *x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() * 100)

    with open('input.txt', 'r') as i:
        results = pool.map(f, i)
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as w:
        w.write(str(results))
```

With an input file of numbers 1 to 420 000, the time to process took 1053.39 seconds (roughly 17.5 minutes), but this is not a good indicator of how long it will take for you, since with the mentioned memory and I/O bound issues, you could end up with something that is significantly slower.

The bottom line is, if you are not maxing out your CPU or RAM or network I/O, then your thread pool is too small.