# Scrape many pages with different "?id=" parameters without excessive requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all pages with different ids from a site that is formatted `url.com/page?id=1`, but there are millions of ids so even at 1 request per second it will take weeks to get them all.

I am a total noob at this so I was wondering if there was a better way than going one by one such as a bulk request or something or should I just increase the requests per second to whatever I can get away with.

I am using `requests` and `beautifulsoup` in python to scrape the pages currently.

Comment: You can do multithreaded web scrapping. Take idea from here and read more about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373167/multithreading-in-python-beautifulsoup-scraping-doesnt-speed-up-at-all

Answer (score 0):

The [`grequests`](https://pypi.org/project/grequests/) library is one possible approach you could take. The results are returned in the order they are obtained (which is not the same order as `event_list`).

```
import grequests

event_list = [grequests.get(f"http://url.com/page?id={req_id}") for req_id in range(1, 100)]

for r in grequests.imap(event_list, size=5):
    print(r.request.url)
    print(r.text[:100])
    print()
```

Note: You are likely to be blocked if you attempt this on most sites. A better approach would be to see if the website has a suitable API you could use to obtain the same information which could be found by using your browser's network tools whilst using the site.